# How to get live plot data from headless Raspberry Pi?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I'm new to using a RaspberryPi. Until now I was experimenting with an Arduino.
If I connect an Arduino by usb it is recognized as COM device and with the Arduino serial plot software it was easily possible to live plot sensor data. 
For my next project I want to work with an Raspberry Pi Zero W and Python. 
Is it possible to send serial data from a python script over the charging usb-cable like with the Arduino? If not, what would be the easiest way to send sensor data e.g. to matplotlib to plot the data directly?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible. However I would not recommend using the USB serial port profile. While it works, it is severely limited in comparison to the alternative. Which is using one of the various ethernet gadget modes.

One tutorial for setting this up is e.g. http://www.circuitbasics.com/raspberry-pi-zero-ethernet-gadget/

The result of this is a full network interface that you can not only use to transfer data over a TCP/IP socket but at the same time run a SSH-connection to start and monitor your application. Even to develop by using a SSH-enabled editor such as Emacs. So the possibilities are much bigger than over the single-stream serial setup.

If it absolutely has to be serial, that's of course possible too - follow e.g. this tutorial: https://learn.adafruit.com/turning-your-raspberry-pi-zero-into-a-usb-gadget/serial-gadget

Comment: Thanks. Do you also have a link to a tutorial with a serial port working even if it is not optimal? Or a hint how I can send and receive the data via tcp and then plot it? Via WLAN I can already access the raspi via SSL and see the prints but I dont know how to plot them.

Comment: I augmented my answer. However I strongly suggest you just learn how to use networking in general. It's the more useful skill. If you can process lines coming over a serial connection, you can process lines coming over a TCP/IP socket. There is little to no difference there, but of network you can have arbitrary many connections, whereas serial is just one.

Comment: Will you work with RPi zero or zero WH? In other words, will you have wifi or not?

Comment: I have a Raspberry Pi Zero W  with wifi.